# json value returning null from mysql varchar

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm trying to get the data from mysql using json. the field type is Varchar(56).
this is my php codes :

```
<?php
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('Cannot connect to the DB');
    mysql_select_db('tugas_akhir', $link) or die('Cannot select the DB');

    /* grab the posts from the db */

    $query = "SELECT ekuivalen
        FROM temp_hasil where username='Dia'";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $link) or die('Errorquery:  '.$query);

    $rows = array();
    while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $rows[] = $r;
    }

    $data = "{aturan:".json_encode($rows)."}";
    echo $data;

    ?>
```

when I run it on firefox it shows

```
{aturan:[{"ekuivalen":null}]}
```

thanks for your help

Comment: is your request returning something in phpmyadmin?

Comment: the query? yes. it return something and is working fine in phpmyadmin

Comment: you can try json_encore(array('aturan" => $rows)); insteand of your $data = .. line, buti donrt think it will resolve your problem

Comment: Insert `print_r($rows)` right after the `while` loop and see what happens

Comment: var_dump($rows, count($rows), json_encode($rows)); will, i  suspect, help to see what is not going well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and discovered the problem is when encoding to json: my varchar field had an `è` (Unicode char) that seemed causing the problem, so I replaced it with `e'` (ASCII chars) and now it works, so...

you should check if there are some `non ASCII chars` in your database fields and replace it.